# What is a difference between C:\Windows\assembly and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly directories?

Tags: .net

I see two directories (C:\Windows\assembly and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly directories?) where .Net DLLs are registered. But I don't know what is the difference between them when .Net DLLs are registered in C:\Windows\assembly and vice verse.

Can everyone help me to explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the default location for the Global Assembly Cache is %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly. In earlier versions of the .NET Framework, the default location is %windir%\assembly.